# Responsive front-end HTML5 framework with Non-Open Source License

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

I want to develop a responsive web application. Is there any framework with Non-Open Source License that would help me build my application? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example, what features should the framework offer? As you speak of non-open-source, what is your price limit?

Answer (score 0):

You want a close-source tool to build interactive web apps?

I can think of three.

- [Xojo, Web Edition](http://www.Xojo.com/)
- [4D](http://www.4D.com)
- [FileMaker](http://www.FileMaker.com/)